# c# LINQ get Attribute value from XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement, xattribute

I have the below XML in a data definitions file:

```
<PQTemplate documentID="CSTrlsEN" documentType="TransList" templateID="001" 
        templateType="Customer Copy" 
        templateName="C:\CPS\_templates\Mini-Statements\CSTrlsEN.doc">  
<field pos="5" name="YPTME" descr="Time"  />
<field pos="6" name="YPDTE" descr="Action Date"  />
<field pos="7" name="YPBRNO" descr="Branch Number"  />
<field pos="8" name="YPBNA" descr="Branch Name"  />
<field pos="9" name="YPTID" descr="Teller ID"  />
<field pos="10" name="YPISN" descr="Teller Sequence"  />
<field pos="11" name="YPREF" descr="Customer Reference"  />
<field pos="12" name="YPCUS" descr="Customer Name"  />
<field pos="13" name="YPEAN" descr="Account Number"  />
<field pos="14" name="YPATY" descr="Account Type"  />
<field pos="15" name="YPCUR" descr="Currency"  />
<field pos="16" name="YPBAL" descr="Available Balance"  />
```

I get that specific XElement using LINQ, extracting it from an XML file that contains several `PQTemplate` elements by using the below LINQ Expression:

```
var mapInfo = from nm in XElement.Elements("PQTemplate")
                where (string)nm.Attribute("documentID") == sRequests[0].Split('\t')[0] 
                select nm;
```

Now I need to get the value of the attribute **documentType** so I tried the below LINQ Expression:

```
var repName = from d in mapInfo.Attributes("documentType")
                     select d.Value;

reportName = repName.ToString();
```

Unfortunately although I can see the value *TransList* is part of the **reportName** element, I have had no luck trying to retrieve it.

Here is an image showing it in VS 2013:

[image]

so how can I get the `documentType` attribute in the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `repName` will return an `IEnumerable<string>` for all the `mapInfo`.

```
IEnumerable<string> repName = from d in mapInfo.Attributes("documentType")
                     select d.Value;
```

So either use a `foreach` loop if you suspect you may get more values or use `First` to get first attribute like this:-

```
string reportName = mapInfo.First().Attribute("documentType").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq queries return collections. Do `for each` over `repName` or

```
repName.First().ToString()
```

if that is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution depends on how many elements `DocumentType` exist in your XML. If it´s only one (what I suppose) you may use `repName.First().ToString()`.

If the attribute may occure more than once you should use a loop instead:

```
var result = new List<string>();
foreach(var a in (from d in mapInfo.Attributes("documentType") select d.Value) 
    result.Add(a.ToString());
```

Or even shorter:

```
result = mapInfo.Attributes("documentType").Select(x => x.Value.ToString());
```

Which will return an enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var mapInfo = from nm in XElement.Elements("PQTemplate")
                where (string)nm.Attribute("documentID") == sRequests[0].Split('\t')[0] 
                select nm;
```

to

```
var mapInfo = from nm in XElement.Elements("PQTemplate")
                where (string)nm.Attribute("documentID") == sRequests[0].Split('\t')[0] 
                select nm.Attribute("documentType").Value;
```

then  `mapInfo.First()` will give you the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

To get a single value out of a LINQ query you have to call for example `First` or `FirstOrDefault`. If you call `FirstOrDefault` it won't throw an exception if the query returns no matches.

```
string repName =  doc.Elements("PQTemplate")
                     .Where(e => (string)a.Attribute("documentID") == sRequests[0].Split('\t')[0])
                     .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("documentType"))
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Also, you don't need to call `ToString()` on `XAttribute.Value` as it's already a `string`.